# How to loop through an Excel table row that has default column headers "Column1", "Column2", etc. and extract the data therein?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel table 'tblData' with default column headers 'Column1', 'Column2', etc. and want to extract the data from each cell in a specific table row. How do I loop through the table row?

Comment: I see no code? Please post your code you have tried.

Comment: Did you search here or on google how to loop throug columns of a data table? [This](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) will give you a good start on how to handle *ListObject Excel Tables*. Looping through rows/columns is a very common task and there are tons of tutorials. Also please always [edit] your question and put all codes there (comments with code are not readable at all). Try it on your own and if you got stuck or errors come back with your code. Also see [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the link which provides a good solution. Is there a solution that does not resort to ListObjects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to the common question:

Example: I have two tables, **tblCall** with real-time call option data, and **tblCallData** to calculate option profit/loss results. tblCallData has 7 columns, with default headers, and 5 data rows. Row 1 contains potential stock price increments in %. I loop through the columns, without using ListObjects or extracting table data to an array, as follows:

```
Sub test() 'Looping through table rows

    Dim callVal as double, callPr as double, stkPr as _
        double, callStr As Double, cl As Integer

    'Get real-time data
    callPr = [tblCall[Call Price]]
    callStr = [tblCall[Call Strike]]
    stkPr = [tblCall[Stock Price]]

    'Loop through stock price increases/decreases
    For cl = 1 To [tblCallData].Columns.Count
        With [tblCallData].Columns(cl)
            'Potential stock price
            .Rows(2) = stkPr * (1 + .Rows(1))         
            'Call option value 
            callVal = .Rows(2) - callStr
            If callVal < 0 Then callVal = 0
            .Rows(3) = callVal
            'Call option profit/loss
            .Rows(4) = callVal - callPr
            'Profit/loss %
            .Rows(5) = .Rows(4) / callPr
        End With
    Next cl

End Sub
```

I hope this example for looping through table rows is of interest.